# What will be the correct Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I am working on a URL rule where i need to identify a particular kind of a url through regx, Those urls will be like,

*Here-Words-Will-Be-Concated-through-hyphens-0000000064-Web.html*

In the above string words (may contain a-z ,A-Z , 0-9) will be glued with a hyphone (-) character. Second last hyphen will trail a integer (0000000064) after that again a (-) and then again a word glued with a dot (.) to 'html' (.html will be fixed for all the possible string at the end part)
I cant figure out the reg x for this.

Comment: like [this](https://regex101.com/r/lK5tP1/1): `[a-z-]+[0-9]+-[a-z]+\.html`

Comment: Actually i am defining a custom URI rule in codeigniter where i need to do something $route['[a-z-]+[0-9]+-[a-z]+\.html'] = "product/viewProduct/$1" to get the integer (0000000064 in my example) as $1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
[\w-]+\d+-\w+\.html
```

demo here :

https://regex101.com/r/kU4lS2/1

to just get the number you need to wrap it up in `()`

like this:

```
[\w-]+-(\d+)-\w+\.html
```

updated demo: https://regex101.com/r/kU4lS2/2

Comment: Thanx aelor, The expression matches but can i extract the integer part (0000000064 in my example) from this as a variable?? i dont know much about regx, Please tell me if it can be achieved.

Comment: @BrijPatel check my update , you will get the number in the capture group `$1`

Comment: I am using PHP and i need to send the (\d+) part as a variable something like $1 to extract the id. I used this (\d+) but getting just the last character '4' instead of whole 0000000064.

Comment: @BrijPatel dont forget the `-` before `(\d+)` .. like this  `[\w-]+-(\d+)-\w+\.html` notice the hiphen I have placed